# What are the negative effects of a flat CMOS battery?

Tags: motherboard, battery, cmos

Recently I have noticed that my computer has been starting up with the time and date incorrect. Given that my motherboard is about 7 years old I'm guessing that the CMOS battery is flat (or close to it).

As far as I know the CMOS battery powers the motherboard's HW clock, and it allows the motherboard keep BIOS settings in its RAM. Are there any other functions that would be negatively affected by a flat CMOS battery?

My reason for asking is that I'm wondering if I can get away with not changing the battery. I think my BIOS settings are at default anyway, so if the only other issue is the system clock then I think I'll just be happy to leave the battery and just resync my clock more frequently.

Comment: why not change the bios battery? It is like the cheapest and easiest thing you can replace in a desktop. Hardest thing would be opening the side of the computer case...

Comment: I think many motherboards retain the clock/settings unless you unplug it from mains power.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing you lose is BIOS settings, your clock, and an annoying warning at every boot. Other than that, nothing else is affected. Unless you need specific BIOS settings, the defaults usually work and you don't need the battery.